# Single Product Page as a Popup

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

When "Buy Now" is clicked, it opens the Single Product Page in a Popup as you can see here

[image]

Now, in this Popup, you notice Featured Image on the left, and Featured Video on the right side, then Product details below the Video.

How do we create something like this? I mean:

1. Display Single Product Page as a Popup.
2. Show Featured Image on the left.
3. Show Featured Video on the right side.
4. Show Product details below the Featured Video on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

The question is slightly vague, so forgive a slightly vague answer.... but the way I would do this is by AJAX request.

1. Click button - add event to listen for the request this would be frontend with Javascript / jQuery and would probably have a `post_id` to request attached to it.
2. Load data - you could do this via the [Wordpress REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/) or add your own endpoint function to return what you need via the established [`admin-ajax.php`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) (you would be looking for the section titled "Ajax on the Viewer-Facing Side" and look into the [`wp_ajax_(action)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) hooks)
3. Parse your data - load into your pop-up the data returned, making sure to add error handling to explain any issues / connection problems or unexpected data.

If I'm talking nonsense above, then you will need a plugin or some cash to pay someone who knows what they're doing. It's not a massive job though if you have a clear design of what you want and clear functionality steps spec'd out.